# Ruby nested array iterations complexity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, nested, time-complexity

I'm writing simple Rails application and I want to get an array of books rated by user, but rate has to be > 0. Now I wonder about the complexity of my query:

```
@ratedBooks = Book.all.select { |book| @user.ratings.select { |rate| rate.rate != 0 }.map { |rate| rate.book }.include? book }
```

Is it n^2 or Ruby is evaluating inner array for every book? Can I do it faster?

Comment: you Book has_many ratings?

Comment: Yup, in models/book.rb. That code works, I wonder about complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your code is very inefficent, since it does all the filtering in the app. You can let the DB do the work:

```
Rating.joins(:book).includes(:book)
      .where(user: current_user)
      .where('rate > 0')
      .map(&:book)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one

```
Book.joins(:ratings).where('ratings.rate>0')
```

so you get all books with an rating higher than 0

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve all ratings from books rated by the user, you could use:

```
@user.ratings.includes(:book).where("ratings.rate != ? and ratings.book_id", 0, book.id)
```